# How Do I Modify This Code From getByID to getByClass?

Tags: javascript

I have been using the following code to replace various text within an id on my page:

```
function setInnerHTML(elementId, innerHTML) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (el) {
        el.innerHTML = innerHTML;
    }
}
```

However, I now need to apply it to more elements and need to change it to using class instead of id. I understand you need to use `getElementsByClassName`, but can't get it to work.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: could put here the code you're trying

Comment: use getElementsByClassName

Comment: @SonuR Oops, typo. Fixed now.

Comment: @scrappedcola I don't think this is dupe of that question. _I now need to apply it to more elements and need to change it to using class instead of id_, OP wants to create a generic function to handle both ID selector and class selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function setInnerHTML(elementClass, innerHTML) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
  for (i in elems) {
    if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + elementClass + ' ') > -1) {
        elems[i].innerHTML = innerHTML;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Working great. Thanks! :)